# how to force interface object to do some indexing action?

Tags: json, go

I got log data source looks like:

> {"LogtypeA":{"content":"listen_logs":[{"useful_key1":val1,"useful_key2":val2},{"useful_key1":val1}]}}

Then I use simplejson to parse them. The value of *listen_logs* is a slice that contain at least one map.
The code is:

```
for _, v := range js.Get("LogTypeA").Get("content").Get("listen_logs").MustArray() {
        _obj := reflect.ValueOf(v)
        fmt.Println(_obj.Kind())
    }
```

If I replace `MustArray()` with `Array()`, it will report incorrect variable and constant declarations.
Using reflect module I will find that the `_obj.Kind()` is map, but I can't use any indexing method to get values from `v` such as:

```
_val1 := v["useful_key1"]
```

or

```
for i, v := range v {...}
```

Because type `interface{}` does not support indexing.
So how should I extract those *useful keyX* from those logs?

Comment: which library you are using you  didn't mentioned here

Comment: Please read https://tour.golang.org/methods/15 or the whole chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a type assertion on the resulting map:

```
new_v := v.(map[string]interface{})
_val1 := new_v["useful_key1"]
```

Or, if you're not sure it will be a map:

```
new_v, ok := v.(map[string]interface{})
if ok {
    // it was a map from strings to something
    _val1 := new_v["useful_key1"]
} else {
    print("Could not interpret v as a map.")
}
```

Since it's initially an empty interface, i.e. `interface{}`, that means it can be any type. So, you need to specify that you want to treat it as a map before trying to access the items.

Comment: Technically this is type assertion, not casting, because you're getting a value of the actual underlying type of the interface, not changing the type.